# Ansible - vmware_guest module to create windows server machine

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a windows server machine with the vmware_guest module from a template. I see that it ignore the parameter disk and its option size_gb. When the playbook create the virtual machine, it has the same disk size of the template This only happens when I create a windows server machine, if I try to create a linux server, the module it works correctly.
This is my playbook

```
    - name: Clone VM from template with static IP
      vmware_guest:
        validate_certs: "{{ validate_certs | default('False') }}"
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        datacenter: "{{ vm_datacenter }}"
        name: "{{ vm_name }}"
        folder: "{{ vm_folder }}"
        template: "{{ vm_template }}"
        state: poweredon
        annotation: "{{ vm_notes | default('Provisioned by ansible') }}"
        cluster: "{{ vm_cluster }}"
        hardware:
          num_cpus: "{{ cpu }}"
          memory_mb: "{{ mem_mb }}"
          hotadd_cpu: "{{ hot_add_cpu | default('True') }}"
          hotremove_cpu: "{{ hot_remove_cpu | default('True') }}"
          hotadd_memory: "{{ hot_add_memory | default('True') }}"
        disk:
          - size_gb: "{{ disk_size | default('16') }}"
            type: "{{ vm_disk_type | default('thin') }}"
            datastore: "{{ vm_datastore }}"
        networks:
          - name: "{{ vm_port_group }}"
            type: static
            ip: "{{ vm_ip }}"
            netmask: "{{ netmask }}"
            gateway: "{{ network_gateway }}"
        wait_for_ip_address: yes
        customization:
          dns_servers:
            - "{{ dns_server1 }}"
      register: static_vm
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try limiting your indentation.  See if that helps.

```
disk:
- size_gb: "{{ disk_size | default('16') }}"
  type: "{{ vm_disk_type | default('thin') }}"
  datastore: "{{ vm_datastore }}"
```